# ros and microcontroller

Tags: ros, microcontroller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can i have a Ros running on a machine and it's interface with a pic micro controller if its is possible then how can it be done?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28696/ros-and-microcontroller/) by [danish](https://answers.ros.org/users/1766/danish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-02-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is the [rosserial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial) stack for communicating with Arduino microcontrollers. This is the closest that I know of to what you're trying to do.

You can find a possible help porting rosserial [here](http://ros.org/wiki/rosserial_client/Tutorials/Adding%20Support%20for%20New%20Hardware).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-02-28**:
If you're going to be making a lot of changes or a lot of different systems, porting rosserial to the PIC will make things easier. If you're building a single system, writing your own protocol and a ROS node to decode it may be easier.